# Remote Desktop as solid as rdesktop that does scaling?

Tags: remote-desktop, ubuntu-12.04, rdesktop

I was using rdesktop until Ubuntu 12.04, then I started using Remmina because it is installed by default.

Remmina, is not *as* bug-free as rdesktop. The keyboard mappings get cross-wired sometimes in Remmina (it seems), and sometime  characters in NotePad (on the remote server) get chopped of at the end (to where the characters are there but you can't see them).

However, the killer feature in Remmina (for me), is scaling. It allows me to magnify the remote desktop to a size my aging eyes appreciate.

Question: is there a program that does scaling, that is as solid as rdesktop, without the bugs of Remmina?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not tried these myself but I believe the following may support scaling:

- [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/) - Remmina seems to be part of this project now but they also have their own client (freerdp-x11 in the Ubuntu repo), is this different to Remmina?
- [Grdc](http://grdc.sourceforge.net/grdc.html) - Correction, this is now [Remmina](http://grdc.sourceforge.net/grdc.html) of course which you have already tried.
- If you can stand some KDE magic, I think that [KRDC](http://www.kde.org/applications/internet/krdc) may also support scaling.